# Is my graphics card dying? Double vision

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card

I need some help. I have been having an annoying problem with my display for a while, and I've gotten fed up with it.

Sometimes, I'll turn off my monitor to go do something and come back. Sometimes when I come back, I'll turn my monitor back on and it will look like this:

[image: Why]

It's not quite double vision as in what 3D looks like without glasses, it's more distorted.

So, I'll try to turn my monitor off and on again, but it still looks like that. Then, I'll unplug my monitor for five minutes and then turn if back on, and now it does something else weird.

It will turn on as if it has a signal, say no signal, go into sleep mode, and then wake up again and the cycle repeats.

The only way to stop this is to restart my computer. Because unplugging/resetting the monitor does nothing, this has led me to believe it may be the graphics card.

I've had my GTX 660 for a little over a couple of years now, is it getting old?

I've tried resetting my Nvidia settings, uninstalling the drivers and re installing, and even using a clean copy of windows and nothing works. I have no other pci ports that my graphics card can go in either.

So is this a problem with my graphics card or not?

Thanks in advance.

Computer specs: i7-3770k, GTX 660, Asus P8H61-M LE/CSM R2.0, 16GB RAM

Monitor: Asus VG248qe

Comment: Possibly related to this: http://superuser.com/questions/1029035/monitor-gets-weird-blurry-display - it didn't get an accepted answer but might have some useful information.

Comment: @Jonno huh, he even has the same monitor as me, I'll check it out! Thanks.

Comment: Although you've confirmed you don't have stereoscopic 3D enabled, it definitely seems related somehow (as per [this thread](http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/11/558752449474796504) and the colour and display looking distinctly like stereoscopic 3D). Unfortunately my hardware set up isn't similar so I don't know any further settings it may be.

Comment: You could try the command `"C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\3D Vision\nvstlink.exe" /disable`, which apparently disables the 3D effect (which I'm convinced is somehow the cause of this.) Just in case it's not looking at the check box for some reason.

Comment: @Jonno Alright, I did that. Hopefully it does not happen again. I'll have to wait a bit to see if it worked, because I have no way to recreate the problem.

Comment: If it does happen again, try running the command at that time and see if it has any effect, in case it's a service starting randomly or something. Definitely worth a poke around your nvidia 3D settings if you see it again

Comment: @Jonno It just happened again, and I tried running the command to no avail. I'm typing this on a blurry monitor so sorry if there are any typos.